# JAVA - Having difficulties with Try / Catch

Tags: java, try-catch

I'm writing a straight forward Airport Terminal style program for class. I'm going beyond the scope of the assignment and "attempting" to use Try/Catch blocks...

However Java is being that guy right now.

The problem is that when someone enters a non-letter into the following code it doesn't catch then return to the try block it caught...

Why?

Edit - Also the containsOnlyLetters method works, unless someone thinks that could be the error?

```
System.out.println("\nGood News! That seat is available");

try
{//try
    System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");
    temp = input.nextLine();
        if (containsOnlyLetters(temp))
            firstName = temp;
        else
            throw new Exception("First name must contain"
                    + " only letters");

    System.out.print("Enter your last name: ");
    temp = input.nextLine();
        if (containsOnlyLetters(temp))
            lastName = temp;
        else
            throw new Exception("Last name must contain"
                    + " only letters");
}//end try

catch(Exception e)
{//catch
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    System.out.println("\nPlease try again... ");
}//end catch

passengers[clients] = new clientInfo
            (firstName, lastName, clients, request, i);
bookSeat(i);
done = true;
```

Comment: Problem is in your ContainsOnlyLetters code. Whats in it?

Comment: Looks like this code tries to discriminate against R2D2?

Comment: I don't know why teachers dont' teach students how to use a debugger. The debugger is REALLY your friend. Are you using eclipse?  click in the gutter of the containsOnlyLetters to set a breakpoint, and use the option debug as application.

Comment: Kudos for going beyond the scope of your assignment.

Comment: +1 for posting a homework question where you've put the effort in advance, instead of expecting someone to write it all for you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand the purpose and mechanism of try/catch.

It's *not* intended for general flow control, and more specifically, the meaning is *not* that the try block is repeated until it finishes without an exception. Instead, the block is run only once, the point is that the catch block will only execute if a matching exception is thrown.

You should use a `while` loop and `if` clauses for your code, not try/catch.

Comment: haha, I was just typing this exact statement. Thanks, saved me some time.

Comment: Thank you. I guess Kid_Programmer is still an acceptable name.

Comment: I guess I need mote help than I thought. I'm not sure how to go about doing that...

Comment: @Kid Programmer: we've all been there. To elaborate: the point of exceptions is that you have the option of *not* catching them immediately and instead catch them one or more levels up the call stack (i.e. the method that called the current one, or the method that called *that* one). And there's the finally clause, to be used when some code *must* run no matter what happens (exception, return, or normal completion).

Comment: @Kid Programmer: yes, that looks pretty good (you'll want to add the error messages you have in your exceptions above).

Comment: @Kid Programmer: to add a little note: the jury is still to decide if checked Java exceptions (the ones you *must* catch) are a good thing or not.  It's pretty much a Java weirdness that a *lot* of languages have been doing perfectly fine *without*.  Checked exceptions are some kind of GOTO statements (flow control, bad, bad).

Comment: @SyntaxT3rr0r: *all* exceptions are some kind of GOTO / flow control, that's not what's problematic about the checked ones (causing leaky abstractions and unnecessary code is).

Answer (score 0):

If a Throwable or Error is generated it won't be caught by your handler. You could try catching Throwable instead.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean when you say

> when someone enters a non-letter into the following code it doesn't catch then return to the try block it caught...

It is not clear the outcome you expect, are u thinking that once the exception is caught, control will go back into the try block? That is not how it is intended to work.

When an exception is thrown, the control goes to the appropriate catch/finally blocks and then moves ahead, remaining lines in the try block are not executed